# Android terminal emulator run executable

Tags: terminal

I am trying to run the linux version of the ctrtool executable to extract the RomFS and ExeFS from a .cxi file, 
but I got an error that said `not executable: magic 7F45`.

The ctrtool executable is in `/storage/sdcard0/Documents/ROMen/`. Is this directory unable to execute files?

Comment: Checkout the answers here: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/139347/96277